# MySQL search with selected options only

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have three tables `movies`, `categories` & `movie_categories`.

**Table: Movies**
| #   | title     |
| --- | --------- |
| 1   | movie - 1 |
| 2   | movie - 2 |
| 3   | tv - 1    |

**Table: Categories**
| # | title     |
| - | --------- |
| 1 | Horror    |
| 2 | Comedy    |
| 3 | (TV)      |
| 4 | Sci-fi    |

**Table: Movie_Categories**
| # | movie_id | category_id |
| - | -------- | ----------- |
| 1 |        1 |           1 |
| 2 |        2 |           4 |
| 3 |        3 |           3 |
| 4 |        3 |           4 |

I am trying to fetch the records which only has `movie_categories.category_id: 3 & 4`

```sql
SELECT `movies`.`title` FROM `movie_categories`
INNER JOIN `movies` ON `movies`.`id` = `movie_categories`.`movie_id`
WHERE `category_id` = 3
AND `category_id` = 4
```

If I use `OR` instead of `AND` then it shows all the records which has either of the selected categories.

What am I doing wrong..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`3` and `4` cannot be valid in a single row.  So, your `where` clause filters out all rows.

You want values in *different* rows, so thing aggregation -- and then filter after aggregation:

```
SELECT mc.movid_id
FROM movie_categories mc
WHERE mc.category_id IN (3, 4)
GROUP BY mc.movie_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;   -- both rows are present
```

Note that your query is also referring to `title`, but that is not in the `movie_categories` database.  You need a `JOIN` (well, there are other ways but that is the most common) to get the title from `movie_id`.  I'll let you work on that.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this. But could you please explain the `Having` part.? I am guessing that the `2` is the count of the selected `categories`. Am I right..?